# How to translate the label content in my partial jquery-template file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-templates

I have to do some translation for my rails application, In my application have template file called dashboard.tmpl at partially rendered in particular part.

```
<div>
    <span>Latest News</span>
    {{if my_recommendations[0]}}
        {{each(i, my_rec) my_recommendations}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}} 
    <p>No News yet.</p>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

I Try to translate the **Latest News**. So try to put <%= t('latest_news')>  this instead. But it can't work. How can I translate that? Please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to translate? This block here  <span>Latest News</span>? Can you show the code that does not work. <span><%=t :latest_news %></span>?

Comment: is `latest_news` label defined in your `config/locales/*.yml`?

Comment: yeah defined in locale file. In my erb file its works, but in tmpl file its not working.

Comment: Can you show code inside jquery that is referencing template...I want to see how you are rendering partial.

Comment: Can you tell us the message/output it gives? So we know what error is happening

Comment: @MirzaMemic, i am calling by ajax like this.


var html = $.tmpl("templates/dashboard.tmpl", { key: value});
              $("#dashboard_ul").append(html);

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro Its shows "<%= t('latest_news') %>"   instead of Latest news. not throwing any error

Comment: is it possible to add .erb to the extension of the file?

Answer (score 1):

After your comment here is the issue. Your templates needs to be generated "on the fly" when you request page. They cannot loaded from file since you need to precompile them first so that rails engine can do the localization.

In short put your templates inside script tag as part of html instead of separate file.

Inside your .html.erb file try to add following code:

```
<script type="text/template" id='news-template'>
  <span><%=t :latest_news %></span>
</script>
```

Then when you want to use it do not load tmp file instead reference it inside html using following

```
var newsTemplate = $('#news-template').html();
```

After you have loaded the template with correct translation you can use it to render

```
$.template( "newsTemplate", newsTemplate );
$.tmpl( "newsTemplate", news ).appendTo( "#news-list" );
```

So inside your template you are not fetching template using file instead you are loading from html page using script tag which you use on client side.

You can check this gem as well https://github.com/jimmycuadra/jquery-tmpl-rails - I have not tried it but maybe they solved this issue.

Hope it helps